# How to float two items in a menu bar

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to float my two menu items in menu bar, but it isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
    <Menu Height="30" Background="#ccc" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <MenuItem Header="New game" Click="NewGame"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="About" Click="AboutWindow" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="CloseWindow" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

And my menu looks like this:

[image: The menu]

Comment: "Float", that's a very HTML way to say it haha

Comment: Do you mean that "About" and "Exit" menu items should be placed on the right?

Comment: @almulo Yeah, I went from web development to desktop apps :)

Comment: @IlVic Yes! That's what I'm aminig for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need just to make some little changes to your XAML:

```
<Menu Height="30" Background="#ccc" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="False" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="New game" Click="NewGame" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="CloseWindow" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    <MenuItem Header="About" Click="AboutWindow" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
</Menu>
```

And this is the result:

[image: Resulting menu]

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `DockPanel` as Items Panel, use `DockPanel.Dock` instead of `HorizontalAlignment`

```
<Menu Height="30" Background="#ccc" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="New game" Click="NewGame"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="About" Click="AboutWindow" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="CloseWindow" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

You were already halfway there :P `HorizontalAlignment` doesn't affect the `DockPanel` behavior, so all your menu items were being docked to the left by default. Your last menu item was shown in the right side just because its container was stretched to fill the remaining space, leaving the menu item space to effectively align itself to the right (in that case, `HorizontalAlignment` had an effect, but only in how the menu item aligned inside its container, not how it was layouted inside the `DockPanel`)

**EDIT** - You may have to change the order in which "About" and "Exit" are defined in XAML, since I don't remember correctly how the precedence worked.